# how to reload hasMany relationship data in ember data 2.8

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

when first time calling model.get('list') its fetching record from server but second time its fetching from store but i want always response from server.

I am using

**Ember js 2.8.3**

**Ember data 2.8.1**

*view model*

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
   list:DS.hasMany('list',{async:true, readOnly: true}), //No I18N
});
```

route model function is like below

```
model:function()
{   
    var model = this.modelFor('view').get('list');
    if(model.get('content.isLoaded'))
    {
        return model.reload();
    }
    return model;
}
```

*same model was making server request always in ember data 1.13.8*

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the fix of problem .

Instead of *model.get('list')*, need to use *model.hasMany('list')*.

```
model:function()
{   
    var model = this.modelFor('view').hasMany('list');
    return model.reload();
}
```